# convert xml to string php with tag

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to convert the following line to a string using

`$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';`

However, `echo $xml_post_string` does not print anything, but when i remove the `<?` from the string, it works. How can I get through this issue?

Comment: How are you viewing the output? Through a web browser? If so, view the source. The content is likely being sent, the browser just isn't rendering it as viewable because it is interpreting it as XML. If you actually want to see that line rendered by the browser, try wrapping it with `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: @PatrickQ, I actually want to send the xml as a soap request later on. I am not sure if the `<pre>` would not be allowed.?

Comment: Trying to output something and trying to send it as a request (such as a SOAP request) are two completely different things.  If you just want to see the output, try what I suggested.  If you want to send a SOAP request, use the built-in [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) methods, which include debugging methods such as [__getLastRequest()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html tag `<xmp>` for that purpose, it renders a container content "as is". But I must note that it's included in the list of "obsolete" elements.

```
$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo "<xmp>".($xml_post_string)."</xmp>";

// the output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```